# error in "mapping" dictonary class

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple mapping class where when keys are 1-1, e.g. `key1:key2, key2:key1`. I'm running into an error when I'm checking to see if the class is equal to a value I enter, I should be getting `True` but I keep getting `False`.

```
>>> m=Mapping()
>>> m[2]=3
>>> m
Mapping({2: 3, 3: 2})
>>> m==Mapping({2: 3, 3: 2})
False
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, my code is below, any help would be appreciated.

```
class Mapping():
    def __init__(self, dic={}):
        self.Dict = dict(dic)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Mapping({})".format(self.Dict)
    def __getitem__(self, loc=0):
        return self.Dict[loc]
    def pop(self, popn=0):
        popm = self.Dict[popn]
        self.Dict.pop(popn, None)
        self.Dict.pop(popm, None)
    def __setitem__(self, x, y):
        self.Dict[x]=y
        self.Dict[y]=x
```

Comment: Implementing `__eq__` might help...

Comment: I don't see any difference in functionality with basic dict. Defining `__eq__ ` magic method would help, but why are you trying to reimplement dictionary based on dictionary?

Comment: @NikolayProkopyev His dict automatically provides the reverse mapping, it appears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Mapping` class has to implement the [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) magic method in order for `==` to work properly. Assuming that two `Mappings` are equal if the `Dict` is equal, you can try somehting like this:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Mapping):
            return self.Dict == other.Dict
        return False
```

Without this, `==` will fall back to checking whether those are the same instance, i.e. what `is` does.

---

Often, when you implement `__eq__`, you would also implement the [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) method, so the two are consistent. Again, you could simply delegate to `self.Dict` for the hash, but `dict` is not hashable (for good reasons, see below), but you could hash the items:

```
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(frozenset(self.Dict.items()))
```

Without `__hash__`, you could e.g. not use your `Mapping` class as key inside another dictionary. However, this setup is problematic, as the `dict` is mutable, so `hash(m)` might change between uses, making it impossible to retrieve the `Mapping` from the `dict` or `set` at a later time.

Comment: You should implement `__hash__` too in this case, right?

Comment: @tobias_k, could you please explain why the `__hash__` is necessary?

Comment: @NikolayProkopyev See my edit. However, in this particular case implementing `__hash__` actually does not make sense, just like for "normal" mutable `dict`.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to guess why :) Your edit looks reasonable. Also, it is probably better to fix words "you should also implement the `__hash__` method", since it is not 100% necessary, and depends.

Comment: Ah yeah, I think I was wrong about implementing `__hash__` - makes more sense without as you say.

Comment: I definitely _wouldn't_ be implementing `__hash__`. Mutable objects that can be hashed are scary! An object that does define `__hash__` must define `__eq__`, but the converse is certainly not true. See [the `__hash__` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)